# Run script when clicking extension icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to do an extension with this behaviour: When I click the extension button, it parses the current page and executes a function for each found item.

**background.js**

```js
            function downloadPage(urlpage,name){
                chrome.tabs.create({
                    url: urlpage
                }, function(tab) {
                    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function func(tabId, changeInfo) {
                        if (tabId == tab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
                            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(func);
                            savePage(tabId, name);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }


            function savePage(tabId, name) {
                chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML({
                    tabId: tabId
                }, function(blob) {
                    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    // Optional: chrome.tabs.remove(tabId); // to close the tab
                    chrome.downloads.download({
                        url: url,
                        filename: 'prueba/test.mht'
                    });
                });
            }
```

**popup.js**

```js
            var candidatos = document.getElementsByClassName("user-name");

            if(candidatos != null){
                for (i = 0; i < candidatos.length; i++) {
                  chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().downloadPage(candidatos[i].href, candidatos[i].text)             
                }

            }
```

**manifest.json**

```js
    {
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "Test",
      "description": "Test",
      "version": "1.0",
      "author": "Pablo",
          "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        },
      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "webNavigation",
        "contextMenus",
        "downloads",
        "<all_urls>",
        "pageCapture"

      ]
    }
```

I can't get to run anything when I click the extension button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Teepeemm added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated:

I have run your code at my end, when you are saying "I can't get to run anything when I click the extension button", I guess you mean `savePage` function in not called. That is because in your callback for `chrome.tabs.create` function, you register `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener, it is too late. I recommend you just use the tab you get from the callback and do what you want.

```
function downloadPage(urlpage,name){
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: urlpage
    }, function(tab) {
        savePage(tab.id, name);
    });
}
```

It's recommended to read the [Official Guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) especially [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction). The basic part should be registering the browser action listener and listening to [onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) event.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    // Do what you want when clicking the 'extension icon'
});
```

Comment: It could still be done with a popup.  Not as well, but possible.

Comment: @Teepeemm, sorry I didn't notice the popup logic in the author's code, just thought he wanted to do something when clicking browserAction. I will also update this answer regarding to his popup code.

Comment: Checked this as correct: it is. Now I have a side question -> How do I get all the elements from the DOM using getElementsByClassName? Because doing document.getElementsByClassName("user-name"); under onClicked doesn't seem to do anything. Thanks in advance @HaibaraAi

Comment: @Pablo, if you mean get all elements from the current webpage, you should know the popup/background page is not in the same context with webpage, you'd better take a look at [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), you can use content scripts / or programming inject it, get the elements you need, then do a message passing between content scripts with popup/background page.

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental problem is that popup.js refers to the DOM of popup.html, which doesn’t have the class or code that you need.  In order to interact with the DOM, you need a content script.  The best approach for that would be to have the background page programmatically inject it.  Then you can also use the callback parameters to avoid having to use message passing:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active:true},function(tabArray){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabArray[0].id,
        {code:"document.getElementsByClassName('user-name');"},
        allFrames);
});

// the parameter to allFrames is the result of code in each frame of the tab
function allFrames(frames) {
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < frames.length ; i++ ) {
        var classes = frames[i];
        for ( var j = 0 ; j < classes.length ; j++ ) {
            downloadPage(classes[j].href,classes[j].text);
        }
    }
}
```

@HaibaraAi’s point is that if the only purpose of the popup is to trigger an action in the background, then it’s much easier to omit the popup and simply have:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,
        {code:"document.getElementsByClassName('user-name');"},
        allFrames);
});
```

And because `tabs.create` gives you a completely loaded tab, you don’t need to listen for its completion.  So we can stick with @HaibaraAi’s version of that function.  The completed example is therefore

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,
        {code:"document.getElementsByClassName('user-name');"},
        allFrames);
});

function allFrames(frames) {
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < frames.length ; i++ ) {
        var classes = frames[i];
        for ( var j = 0 ; j < classes.length ; j++ ) {
            downloadPage(classes[j].href,classes[j].text);
        }
    }
}

function downloadPage(urlpage,name){
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: urlpage
    }, function(tab) {
        savePage(tab.id, name);
    });
}
```

With your original `savePage`.  And you no longer need the popup.  (Also, the `activeTab` permission is contained in the `tabs` permission, so you don’t need that.)